# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asarray'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am using the Spyder IDE via Anaconda but the Numpy asarray method won't work.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im = Image.open("photo.jpg", "r")
data = np.asarray(im)
print(data)
```

Based similar questions it is recommended to make sure there is no other file called numpy.py in the current directory, but I have checked and the only files are this .py and the image referenced.

Comment: What's your numpy library version?

Comment: `print(np.__file__)` and show us what you get.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica it returns None